# Dockerized Node js app does not start

Tags: node.js, macos, express, docker

After dockerizing my demo Express js app and starting the container, I am unable to access the service due to a `"Connection Timeout"`

Url for the for project before dockerizing (***Which produced "Hello world!" on the browser***):

```
http://localhost:3000/cars/example/fetchResult
```

Url for the project after starting the docker container (Gives a "***172.17.0.2 took too long to respond.***")

```
http://172.17.0.2:3000/cars/example/fetchResult
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

I built my docker image like

```
docker build -t prasannarb/example-node-service
```

I started my docker image as a container like

```
docker run -t prasannarb/example-node-service
```

Then when I, `docker ps`, it gives me

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7cf955f5d799        prasannarb/example-node-service   "node server.js"    About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3000/tcp            thirsty_perlman
```

`docker inspect 7cf955f5d799` gives me `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`

Since I did not explicitly give a port to start my container, I was assuming it would take the same as exposed by my docker container (3000) which is the same port where my service would listen too.

What am I doing wrongly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EXPOSE` instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime. `EXPOSE` does not make the ports of the container accessible to the host.

To do that, you must use either the `-p` flag

Your `docker run` command should look like this:

```
$docker run -p3000:3000 -t prasannarb/example-node-service
```

Additionally, the `docker inspect` command give you the container IP address, not the host IP address.

Comment: Passing the port explicitly with -p parameter worked. And yes, I was trying to access the url through the container's IP and later realized that I should be using the host IP with the provided port to access the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue when working on a **Node JS** app using **Docker**.

When I check the logs for the docker app using the command:

```
docker logs <container-id>
```

it shows that the app is connected and synced to the database:

> Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'tbl_user_skills' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
> Database Connected and Synced

But when I run the command:

```
curl localhost:3000
```

to check the app, I get the error below:

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I've checked the AWS security group for the server where the app is deployed and it's open for port `3000`.

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was that the port which I exposed in the Dockerfile is not the port that the app is listening to.

I did an exec into the docker container to check the logs using the command:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/sh
```

Next, I checked the logs files (`error.log` and `info.log`) which are located in the `logs` folder:

```
# cd logs
# cat error.log
# ls
error.log  info.log  warnings.log
# cat info.log
info: Apr-03-2022 09:08:41:     Server started at : http://localhost:5010
info: Apr-03-2022 09:08:41:     Database Connected and Synced
```

I found out from the `info.log` file that the node server of the app was configured to run on port `5010` in the `config/config.json` file of the Node JS project.

All I had to do was to adjust the Docker exposed port from `3000` to `5010` as well as change the port that the Docker container runs from port `3000` to port `5010`. Furthermore, changed the AWS security group of the server where that app is being deployed to allow port `5010` instead of port `3000` and this time everything ran fine.